# What is StackExchange?

Tags: support, questions

Is there a different community?

Than English Langage Learners for English Learning?

Where can I find the FAQ?

How can I learn here if half the resources are on Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely speaking, StackExchange is a collection of Q&A communities focusing on specific fields. You can find all the sites here: [StackExchange Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#).

There are many different sites. If you are learning English and have **specific** questions on grammar, meaning, or some other related matter, then you're in the right place!

However, we do have several guidelines. I know: the help center is not exactly the easiest thing to find. Actually, I personally don't even know how to find it on the app. On the browser, in the current format, if you click the icon that looks like a speech bubble with three lines, 
[image]

you will find a button that says "help". That link will take you to the [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help). The Help Center will answer most of your questions regarding ELL. Most of the guidelines also apply to the other SEs.

The link I most commonly share is this *(Help Center > Asking)*: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). There, you will find a guideline that is specific to our site. If you visit a different SE and visit their "Asking" page, then you will find a guideline suited to that SE.

Our "Asking" page gives a list of questions that are on-topic here ("acceptable"). You will also find a link to [Please, everyone... details. Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187). This gives a guideline on how to improve your questions for our site. We often ask for your own research and understanding of the problem. You will find good examples in that post.

Additionally, we also have the [Contributor's Guide to English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/36187). This is an effort to collect helpful resources and tips for contributors (asking and answering). You can find more tips to help you ask questions here. If I were to pick one tip to share though, it would be *provide as much relevant context as possible*. This will help respondents better understand your problem and help protect your post from close votes and down votes.

Comments that direct you to Google and not a specific resource are not constructive. It may even border on "unfriendly", according to our [Code of Conduct](https://ell.stackexchange.com/conduct). I deleted a comment instructing you to search something on Google. I didn't think the user had any bad intent, but I also didn't find the comment to be particularly helpful. In general, if you see a comment that is not constructive, obsolete, unkind, or unfriendly (as outlined in the CoC), then you are encouraged to [flag it](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/flagging).

Yes, there are many resources you can find through Google and we do generally expect some research from you. But broadly telling you to Google your problem is not acceptable behavior here on the SE network. Google can help you get started learning; we can help you finish.

Comment: Hello, can you tell me how to close an answered Question and how can I remove the ones that put on hold?

Comment: @Jacob Unless there is an extraordinary circumstance, we don't remove answered questions. It is not allowed and, if you delete it, a moderator may undelete it. Try searching the Help Center for your questions regarding the how the site works. About closed/on hold questions, see [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: If you're concerned about [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186392/what-this-word-nip-mean), you did not improve it in my opinion. Actually, I think you made it worse since asking for "more examples" is too broad and, again, is answerable with a dictionary (many dictionaries provide many examples).

Comment: Please improve your question(s) by **providing research or more details** (or whatever the close reason banner suggests). After you edit a question, usually you have to wait for your question to be reviewed in one of the queues. However, I already kicked it off the queue earlier (before you left your comment here). Since I already kicked it off once, it will not return to the queue if you edit your post. So in _this_ particular situation, if you do improve it (with details/research), then leave me a comment here or flag your post with a custom reason explaining that you want the post reopened.