# Why I have " You have reached your question limit" if I do not have any question bad in my account here?

Tags: discussion

I do not know really because I have **You have reached your question limit** does not have any vote closed?

because I have this: **You have reached your question limit**    if I do not have question bad?

Answer (score 5):

It's not true that none of your questions have been downvoted or closed.  In fact, you have three deleted questions:

- https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156228/ (deleted, closed, score -1)
- https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186247/ (deleted, closed, score 0)
- https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174458/ (deleted, closed, score -3)

Even though these questions are deleted, they still count toward your question ban.  Please see [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/215040) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> If a post was poorly-received (downvoted or closed), that will continue to count against your account **even if the post is deleted**! Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting them.
>
> Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions if less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question.

We can't remove your question ban, unfortunately.  If you'd like to ask more questions, consider **editing your existing questions** to improve them.  Fix their formatting and grammar, and make sure the questions themselves make sense.  Include enough context for the questions to be answerable.  If you think you can improve one of your deleted questions, consider editing it and undeleting it.  If enough people upvote your questions, the ban will be removed.

For examples of good ELL questions, please see this meta post: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4584/230

Comment: Are any of the deleted questions outside the 60-day window? If so, simon might benefit from links to them.

Comment: oh thanks I  am so sorry if my question are bad but I am not native english speaker

Comment: @simon We only expect you to write to the best of your ability, so it’s not a problem that you’re still learning. The easiest improvement you can make is to explain in your questions what you found when you looked for an answer before you posted. Did you look up words in a dictionary? If so, explain why that didn’t help. There is lots of advice here on meta for asking questions that will be well-received, like some of the posts listed in https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4784/.