# Profile info in contributor's guide?

Tags: discussion, advice

[This answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5548/91457) has been proposed for the [Contributor's Guide to English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) (which I recommend). It suggests things that a contributor might want to include in his or her profile. Is this the sort of advice we want to include in the Contributor's guide?

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Just FYI, I made several edits to the proposed text, mostly to make it more applicable to ELL contributors who aren't English language learners. Please feel free to revert any changes I made that stray from what you intended.

Comment: MarcInManhattan Thanks. However, I neither wrote not edied that part of the  *Contributor's Guide*, so I have no intent to be preserved. Another user, in fact @ColleenV, questioned whether that answer should form part of the *Guide*, and I was hoping for feedback on that question.

Comment: Oh, I see that now. My mistake.

Comment: I don't think we want to strong-arm folks into putting certain things into their profile, but I don't see any reason why we couldn't suggest adding certain information that might be helpful.

Comment: I don't see the wording of the current answer as "strong-arming" anyone, and the information mentioned might indeed be helpful. I will add a statement that no one is required to add any of this information or indeed to set up a profile at all. With that I don't have a problem with the amswer. Does anyone else?

Comment: I think the current wording is fine... my objection to adding it to the Contributor's Guide wasn't because I thought it was a bad idea, but because we hadn't really decided as a community it was something we wanted to encourage.